Angular function not firing upon route change
Here are my codes:

profile.component.html

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of profile">
...
</ng-container>

<app-content [content]="content"></app-content>

<app-content [content]="content"></app-content> is my main page (content.component).

profile.component.ts

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.profId = +params['id'];

      this.getUser();
      this.getUserContent();
    });
}

getUser() {}
getUserContent() {}


content.component.html (the link to navigate to user's profile page)

<span class="name bold-text" [routerLink]="['/profile', item.author_id]">
     {{ item.username }}
</span>

I am using Angular 18. When I navigate from main page to profile page by clicking user 1, it will load user 1's profile information and content posted. However, when I click on user 2 FROM user 1's profile, it only load user 2's profile information but not the content posted. Further troubleshooting reveals that this.getUser() fired, but not this.getUserContent().

Hi @L1N3NM3L0N, your main page is content.component so it have the router-outlet I guess. Then navigates to '/profile' which loads profile.component and this one includes again your main page 'content.component' ? may is losing the router-outlet trace. Could you create any little demo?

Thank you for your answer. I've figured out it was because I was appending to my content instead of replacing it. Spent so long just to realise it was this silly mistake. But you reminded me to update all my routing to latest Angular routing method. Muchas gracias :)

Managed to figure out what's wrong.
I was appending to my content instead of replacing it. The functions and routing work fine as it is.
Regarding this.getUserContent() not firing, I've changed to the latest Angular routing method.

app.config.ts

providers: [
  provideRouter(appRoutes, withComponentInputBinding()),
]


profile.component.ts

@Input()
  set id(id: string) {
    if (id) {
      this.profId = id;
      this.getProfile(id);
      this.getUserPosts(id);
    }
  }

Now both functions fire upon changes in route.

Great @L1N3NM3L0N :)!
